# iTunes stops working every time I launch it

Tags: itunes

Recently I've updated my iTunes to the latest version, 11.4.0.18. Prior to updating it, iTunes didn't stop working, neither did it have any problems. Only after I updated it to the latest version, the dialog box will come up with "iTunes has stopped working" every time iTunes is launched.

Edit:
I'm running on Windows 8.1, 64-bit. The user profile I'm using is an Administrator account.

Comment: Would you edit your question to include whether you're running iTunes on Windows or OS X. The fix will likely be related to fit changing permissions in your home folder which requires knowledge of the system

Answer (score 1):

That version of iTunes is for Microsoft Windows.

I suggest that you follow the instructions in [this Apple troubleshooting article.](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1717)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by uninstalling my current itunes and all its related programs. And then install the previous itunes version.

It worked instantly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem after upgraded to iTunes 12.7 and there is no useful solution. If you disconnect from network itunes works fine.

**You can try safe mode**

hold <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd> and double click iTunes. You will be asked for admin credential but iTunes works then.